# Method overloading and default return type of a parameterized method

Tags: java, overloading

I have the following setup:

```
public class SomeUtil {

    public static void doSmth(boolean b) {
        System.out.println("boolean");
    }

    public static void doSmth(String b) {
        System.out.println("string");
    }

    public static void doSmth(Object b) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }
}
```

```
public interface SomeCl {
    <T> T getAttribute(Object var1);
}
```

```
public class SomeClImpl implements SomeCl {
    @Override
    public <T> T getAttribute(Object var1) {
        Boolean o = Boolean.TRUE;
        return (T)o;
    }
}
```

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeCl someCl = new SomeClImpl();
        SomeUtil.doSmth(someCl.getAttribute(Boolean.TRUE));
    }
}
```

And when I run the main method the execution fails with a ClassCastException:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Boolean and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') at Demo2.main(Demo2.java:4)

So the question is: why is JVM trying to cast Boolean to String? Why not to Object?

p.s. please do not advice me to cast it manually before **someCl.getAttribute(arg)** method calling or call it like **someCl.</</DesiredType/>/>getAttribute(arg)**

Comment: Note you have a `Boolean` object in the `SomeClImpl#getAttribute` method. You then cast that to `T`. _This_ is where the CCE arises, because you called `doSmth(someCl.getAttribute(...));`. Note the parameter you passed to `#getAttribute` doesn't matter, it just accepts `Object`. Using `<T> T` without any type of token is _dangerous_ for this reason: try passing a `Class<T>` parameter, which would let you do `someCl.getAttribute(boolean.class)` to call the boolean method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler chooses to call `doSmth(String b)` instead of `doSmth(Object b)` because of the language rule for [choosing the most specific method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

The compiler doesn't know the type of the argument you pass to `doSmth`, which has a generic return type, so it chooses the most specific method.

Comment: Then why `doSmth(String b)` is more specific than `doSmth(boolean b)`, which is applicable for a boxed Boolean extends Object?

Comment: @gdomo when choosing between the `doSmth` overloads, it uses only the type of argument passed, which is a generic type, which can't possibly be the primitive `boolean`. It _may_ be a `Boolean` which is an `Object` but it can only choose between `Object` and `String`.

Comment: I believe a more accurate version of the answer would contain the exact rule which I managed to identify from the referred section by myself: 
"If no preferred method exists according to the above rules, then a maximally specific method is preferred if it:
has a signature that is a subsignature of every maximally specific method's signature; and
is return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for every maximally specific method."